# What happens to a President's reelection funds if they don't complete their first term?

Tags: united-states, campaign-finance

Trump's 2020 re-election campaign recently filed their [required FEC statements](http://www.fec.gov/fecviewer/CommitteeDetailCurrentSummary.do?tabIndex=1&candidateCommitteeId=P80001571&electionYr=2018), showing they had [raised](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/04/14/us/politics/trump-raises-millions-for-2020-re-election-bid.html?_r=0) [$13.2 million](http://www.foxnews.com/politics/2017/04/15/report-trump-reelection-effort-raised-13-2-million-so-far-in-2017.html) so far.  It's safe to assume at this time that Trump does, in fact, intend on running for a second term, like almost every other first-term President has.  It's way too soon to tell if he will have a serious primary challenge (unlike most incumbent Presidents), but even if he does, he can clearly spend these campaign funds on that election.

However, what happens if Trump *can't* run for a second term?  What happens to his campaign funds if he is impeached (and actually removed), resigns, or dies in office?

Comment: Coldn't this simply be asked as (more generic) "What happens to a candidate's election funds if he stops being a candidate?" (which BTW I think already exists and has an answer).

Comment: @SJuan76 - Possibly, but this concerns money raised long before the actual campaigning starts.  It may have the same answer, though.

Comment: I'm tempted to raise the question "What happens to a former SoS' election funds if she's convicted to jail time?" It's as pointless and politically loaded as this question.

Comment: @Sjoerd - I was trying to be neutral about it - I've retitled the question.  A sitting first-term President (regardless of who it is) is the only person I can think of who would be *expected* to run this far out from an election. And a lot can happen in three years, so it's a viable question to wonder what happens to all that money if he has a heart attack or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Federal election law allows campaign donations to be used for many different things. Although most people imagine their contributions will be used to, you know, fund a campaign, campaign contributions can also be used for:

- Necessary expenses for holding the office.
- Donations to candidates for state and local offices.
- Transfers to the committee of a political party (at any level - national, state, etc.)
- Donations to governmental units (IRS - 170(c) )

These uses, as well as prohibited uses, begin on page 58 of [this FEC collection](http://www.fec.gov/law/feca/feca.pdf) of election law.

The explanation of 170(c) organizations can be found on page 1, part B of this [IRS document](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-tege/eotopice85.pdf).

Comment: Interesting. This is exactly what I was looking for. Also, I hadn't realized the funds could be used for ongoing expenses of holding the office. That puts a different spin on Trump's already collecting for 2020.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The funds can go towards the Republican National Committee for other elections, such as Senate and House.

One such fund is a joint fundraising effort as seen at the footer of [Trump's online shop](https://shop.donaldjtrump.com/):

[image]

Comment: You need to explain why this is likely to be true.